# jQuery Issue with mouseleave for an Overlapping Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseleave

I'm somewhat new to jQuery and have a basic question. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
$(".v65-productDisplay a img").each(function(){
var productHref = $(this).attr("src");
var productCode = productHref.substring(19,productHref.length-6);
```

This is in the Volusion framework and a lot of things are dynamically generated. The product images all have anchor tags that link to the product but the anchor nor the image have ids or classes. I'm able to grab the Product Code from the product by targeting the href attribute of the anchor tag since the links use get variables. An example would be `/v/vspfiles/photos/MacFRC-1.jpg` where MacFRC is the Product Code.

Now I'm trying to generate an add to cart button and you can set those up with GET variables so for this one, the link (from within the store) would be `/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=MacFRC`. Here's the code I'm using to generate that as a hover over effect on the img. Not that $(this).parent() is targeting the anchor tag that's the parent of the image. I'm doing it this way because there are other anchor tags within .v65-productDisplay but are using spans and I'm just dealing with the image ones.

```
$(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().append("<div id='hover_info' style='position:relative;top:-20px;'><div id='add_hover'><a href='/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=" + productCode + "'>Add To Cart</a></div></div>");
})
    .mouseleave(function() {
    $("#hover_info").remove();
});
```

Now the issue is that when I go to hover over the newly generated 'hover_info' div that has the link, it disappears. I'm guessing this is because technically I'm 'mouseleave'ing the img at that point and the jQuery is running to remove the div.

Is there a way to set functions in jQuery to something like 'if my mouse leaves this element as well as all of it's child elements'? That's kind of what I'm looking for I think.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My head is spinning. Need a demo of the issue. Also, what is a "GET variable"?

Comment: Hi @Beetroot-Beetroot, the GET variable is a form variable (as opposed to a POST variable). It's tacked onto the URL so the server side script can interpret what to do. That's how Volusion allows you to add items to the shopping cart with a direct link.

Comment: Server-side, such a variable may be referred to as a "GET variable". As we are client-side here, "URL querystring parameter" or just "querystring parameter" would be a better term.

Answer (score 0):

There is also mouseout event which is triggered when mouse leaves element or its child, but I think it's not what you are looking for.

What you can do is to check if mouse is over div when mouseleave-ing image and do the same for div - check if mouse is over image on mouseleave-ing div.
you can use .is(":hover") to check this but its not working for all browsers so I would better add/remove class to distinguish this.

```
$(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hovered").parent().append("<div id='hover_info' style='position:relative;top:-20px;'><div id='add_hover'><a href='/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=" + productCode + "'>Add To Cart</a></div></div>");    
})
.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hovered"); 
    if (!$(this).parent().find("#hover_info").hasClass("hovered")) 
        $(this).parent().find("#hover_info").remove();
});
```

and add mouseenter mouseleave for #hover_info, just use "live" (or "on") so that event handlers could be bound even if element does not exist yet

```
$("#hover_info").live({
    mouseenter: function() { 
        $(this).addClass("hovered");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hovered");
    if (!$(this).parent().find(".v65-productDisplay a img").hasClass("hovered"))
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```